# How to perform ifelse on multiple columns?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have sample dataframe

```
dat <- data.frame(
  variable1 = c(NA,2,3,4,5,6,99),
  variable2 = c(NA,2,99,4,5,6,7),
  variable3 = c(NA,2,3,4,5,6,7),
  variable4 = c(5:11),
  variable5 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,999),
  variable6 = c(1,2,3,4,999,6,7),
  variable7 = c(1:7)
)

  variable1 variable2 variable3 variable4 variable5 variable6 variable7 
1        NA        NA        NA         5         1         1         1 
2         2         2         2         6         2         2         2 
3         3        99         3         7         3         3         3 
4         4         4         4         8         4         4         4
5         5         5         5         9         5       999         5
6         6         6         6        10         6         6         6
7        99         7         7        11       999         7         7
```

I want to perform an ifelse saying if variable1 and variable2 and variable3 are NA,
take variable4, variable5, variable6,
otherwise take variable1, variable2, variable3
to the new columns
variable 8, variable9, variable10.

so the new data frame should look like this

```
  variable1 variable2 variable3 variable4 variable5 variable6 variable7 variable8 variable9 variable10
1        NA        NA        NA         5         1         1         1         5         1         1
2         2         2         2         6         2         2         2         2         2         2 
3         3        99         3         7         3         3         3         3        99         3
4         4         4         4         8         4         4         4         4         4         4 
5         5         5         5         9         5       999         5         5         5         5
6         6         6         6        10         6         6         6         6         6         6
7        99         7         7        11       999         7         7         99        7         7
```

I prefer a dplyr solution ;)

Comment: What if only one of variable 1, 2 or 3 are `NA`?

Comment: `mutate(dat, map2_dfc(across(1:3, .names='{.col}_new'), across(4:6), coalesce))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dplyr::case_when` is perfect for this:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>% 
  mutate(across(all_of(1:7), ~as.numeric(.))) %>% #important for all data to be numeric
  mutate(variable8 = case_when(is.na(variable1) & is.na(variable2) & is.na(variable3) ~ variable4,
                               TRUE ~ variable1)) %>%
  mutate(variable9 = case_when(is.na(variable1) & is.na(variable2) & is.na(variable3) ~ variable5,
                               TRUE ~ variable2)) %>%
  mutate(variable10 = case_when(is.na(variable1) & is.na(variable2) & is.na(variable3) ~ variable6,
                               TRUE ~ variable3))

  variable1 variable2 variable3 variable4 variable5
1        NA        NA        NA         5         1
2         2         2         2         6         2
3         3        99         3         7         3
4         4         4         4         8         4
5         5         5         5         9         5
6         6         6         6        10         6
7        99         7         7        11       999
  variable6 variable7 variable8 variable9 variable10
1         1         1         5         1          1
2         2         2         2         2          2
3         3         3         3        99          3
4         4         4         4         4          4
5       999         5         5         5          5
6         6         6         6         6          6
7         7         7        99         7          7
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

dat %>% 
  mutate(pmap_dfr(., ~ (if (all(is.na(c(...)[1:3]))) {c(...)[4:6]} else 
    {c(...)[1:3]}) %>% set_names(str_c("variable", 8:10))))

#>   variable1 variable2 variable3 variable4 variable5 variable6 variable7
#> 1        NA        NA        NA         5         1         1         1
#> 2         2         2         2         6         2         2         2
#> 3         3        99         3         7         3         3         3
#> 4         4         4         4         8         4         4         4
#> 5         5         5         5         9         5       999         5
#> 6         6         6         6        10         6         6         6
#> 7        99         7         7        11       999         7         7
#>   variable8 variable9 variable10
#> 1         5         1          1
#> 2         2         2          2
#> 3         3        99          3
#> 4         4         4          4
#> 5         5         5          5
#> 6         6         6          6
#> 7        99         7          7
```